# Launching with one ViewController on navigation stack

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm trying to achieve the effect similar to the native Mail application in iOS 7 where the initial view controller on launching already has the "Mailboxes" view controller in the back stack. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Either Storyboard or programmatic would be fine.

In the app delegate didFinishLaunching I've tried creating an initial view controller (A) embedded in a navigation controller and then pushing a new view controller (B), and then setting that new view controller to be the window's root view controller but when B appears it doesn't have a navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set that new view controller to be the window's root view controller, the navigation controller should be the window's root view controller. Just push that second controller with no animation, and that's all you should have to do.